# format for url to point to radio button selection

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linking to a radio button selection, asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748928/linking-to-a-radio-button-selection-asp-net-c)

i have a page with a textarea and radio buttons. the text area is populated with data based on the radio button selection. i want the radio button selection to appear in the url so that a user can link to the radio button selection.

i'm hoping that all i need to do i modify my querystring to include radio button value. here's the data caputered by fidler when i make a radio button selection.

```
 __EVENTTARGET  ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1$6
__EVENTARGUMENT 
__LASTFOCUS 
__VIEWSTATE /+++PC9wPg0KPHA+/....
__EVENTVALIDATION   /wEWCwKY7d6oAQLh8vmTCALk7M7lDQK+6NunDwK/6OenDwK86OenDwK86OunDwK86POnDwK96NenDwK96NunDwKxh73KA3Q+PMuKU/JUCKsF1aiY2DNLu7/pFFni/Qtz+7FXy35g
ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1  41
```

i'm hoping my url simply needs to look something like this to point to the radio button value but and all i need is the appropriate syntax:

```
http://www.test.com/test.aspx?ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1$41
```

---code behind ---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {


            RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            RadioButtonList1.DataBind();

        }

        else
        {

            string strRedirect;

            strRedirect = "frm_Articles.aspx?Article_PK=" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

            Response.Redirect(strRedirect);


        }
    }  



    protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

  //    

    }
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        try{
        e.Command.Parameters["@URL_FK"].Value =  Session["URL_PK"];


        }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }


    }



}
```

Comment: A question jsut occured to me... how does your page currently change the text based on the radio button? The code above seems to suggest that on postback it does a redirect leading me to think that either a) you are doing it client side or b) that the page you are redirecting to is the one you want picking up the value, not test.aspx. Does http://www.test.com/frm_Articles.aspx?Article_PK=41
actually do what you want?

Comment: I'm getting a psychic vibration from your question.  It says... Ask your kids, "what were the three best things that happened today"

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that you have misconstructed your url. It should be:

```
http://www.test.com/test.aspx?ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1=41
```

(note the third to last character is an =.

Apart from that it would depend on how your page works in terms of picking up the selected radio button. My advice would be to just try it and see what happens. However, I would suspect that if you are doing it based on an event firing on page load (ie some kind of postback behaviour) then it won't work.

If this is the case then you will just want to do something on page load to check if that value exists in the url and set it before you load up the text. If you end up going down this route you might want to consider using a more well defined and user friendly querystring parameter. In particular the id you have there is built based on its position in the control hierarchy. If you were to redesign your HTML structure the ID might well change.

**Additionally...**

With the code you've provided where you set the selectedindex of your radiobutton list you need to find out what value you need before you set it and set it to 0 if you have no better value (though it looks like you are setting to 0 before binding whcih seems superfluous). Something like this may work (not compiled or tested so apologies for typos - it is designed to give you the general idea more than to be finalised code).

```
if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
{
    RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
    //Check if you have a value to set.
    if (Request.Querystring(RadioButtonList1.ClientID)!=null)
    {
        //Get the value
        string setValue = Request.Querystring(RadioButtonList1.ClientID)
        //Find the right radio option to select
        foreach(ListItem item in RadioButtonList1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Value == setValue)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I assume it will default to the selected index being 0 if nothing is set as selected otherwise.

Anyway, this code is meant as a starting point to work from. There may be other ways to do it and some may even be better.

Comment: thanks. the url didn't give me the results i was looking for :/

Comment: I'm guessing then that you will need to add a bit of code to the server to check on first load (ie not postback) whether you have something in the url and take action as appropriate.

Comment: how can i set up a check? i posted my current code behind. thank you.

Comment: @MG: Edited my answer to add in some comments on that.

Comment: item.Value and item.Selected are throwing errors. 'object' does not contain a definition.

Comment: I guess it didn't decide on the right object type. I've just edited it to not use var (I was feeling lazy and hadn't looked up the exact object type). If my edit still doesn't work then just look up what type of object you'd expect (or use the debugger to see) and check it that way. A cast would probably do the trick too.

Comment: ok, i got it to run. so should i be able to use the url above and get pass the radiobutton value to the page on pageload?

Comment: I believe so. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of my new code and watch what happens. It should get find the value in the url, set the one you chose to setValue and then loop through all the radiobuttons looking for the one you've asked for. If it doesn't do that then looking in the debugger should help you work out why not.

Comment: still not able to pass the value to set the radio button on page load: `http://www.test.com/test.aspx?ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1=41` ...frustrating...debugging again..

Comment: if i put in the entire string after the url, it points to the correct radio button. `__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24MainContent%24RadioButtonList1%242&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%%2ByiD%2Ff2wmeKTuUwe9Ing%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWCQKVn9%....2BLYkev3csEzPfS6PI4lPJbP&ctl00%24MainContent%24RadioButtonList1=14` is there anyway to cut this down?

Comment: What is the logical flow when you try it with that cut down url? Does it pick up that value at all? does it fail to set a radio button? Does it do something else? You've got to give me a bit more than "it doesn't work" or I'm left relying on my poor psychic powers to try to work out where you are going wrong.