# linking to a radio button selection, asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

on the search for an answer to save the day.

I have an "articles" page that holds a radiobutton list and a textarea. when the user selects a radio button, the text area is populated. now the users wants to be able to point to an article via a url link. (everything is dynamic and being pulled from a db source)

by using a 3 party tool i was able to grab the exact http request (below) that will link to the users' selection. the problem is the url is extremely long. is there another way to link to the radio button selection? that way i can just modify the query string to fit a specific format. thanks.

url to specfic radio button selection ---------------

```
http://localhost:60062/test/test_articles.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24MainContent%24RadioButtonList1%243&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTEyMjYyNjEzNjcPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgoCAQ8PZA8QFgFmFgEWAh4OUGFyYW1ldGVyVmFsdWUFFmh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NjAwNjIWAQIFZGQCBw9kFgICAw8PFgIeBFRleHQFATBkZAIJDzwrAA8CAA8WBB4LXyFEYXRhQm91bmRnHgtfIUl0ZW1Db3VudAIBZAoQFgAWABYAFgJmD2QWBmYPDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkAgEPZBYCZg9kFgJmDxUBRUFzayB5b3VyIGtpZHMsICJ3aGF0IHdlcmUgdGhlIHRocmVlIGJlc3QgdGhpbmdzIHRoYXQgaGFwcGVuZWQgdG9kYXk%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%2ByiD%2Ff2wmeKTuUwe9Ing%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWCQKVn9%2FvDwLh8vmTCALk7M7lDQKp6JekDwKm6JekDwK%2B6OenDwK%2B6OunDwK86OOnDwKxh73KAwOihkx44beFhpVDoerFt%2BLYkev3csEzPfS6PI4lPJbP&ctl00%24MainContent%24RadioButtonList1=15
```

Comment: In fact, this is the actual same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745685/format-for-url-to-point-to-radio-button-selection isn't it? Or is there a subtle difference that I've not noticed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pass the ViewState around. What you need to do is put a simple parameter in the QueryString. Make the url something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/MyPage.aspx?selected=1
```

Then look for that parameter in the codebehind and select the button server-side.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int selected;

        if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["selected"], out selected))
            RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MG: You don't have to have it in Page_Load. You can put it wherever the textarea is getting populated, or in one of the other page lifecycle events. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

Just use the  anchor tag or one of the hyperlink controls. I'm not sure exactly what you did to get all the postback data but it sounds like you don't need any of that.

Comment: if i strip out any of the postback data, it can't succesfully point to the radio button selection.

Comment: Your terminology seems very vague to me. If you need to do this by URL, then you might need to pass the selected item in the URL as a querystring argument. This probably means that you need to update your existing code so that your radio buttons instead redirect to the page with the correct querystring argument. Then your page can select the appropriate radio button when it loads according to that argument.